How to set text in multiple Editboxes ribbon Excel?
I have created a custom tab ribbon excel interface.
I have two editBox, but one callback macro.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI 
                   onLoad="OpenFile"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
<tab 
              id="customTab" 
              label="Exsem" 
<tabs>
        <editBox
              id = "editBox1"
              getText = "MacroGetText" />
        <editBox
              id = "editBox2"
              getText = "MacroGetText" />

This code works fine:
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI
Public TextInEditBox As String

Sub OpenFile(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
            Set myRibbon = ribbon                                                                      
            TextInEditBox = ""
End Sub

Private Sub MacroGetText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    text = TextInEditBox
End Sub

I can change the value in one editBox:
Public Sub MyTest()
    TextInEditBox = "1"
    myRibbon.InvalidateControl ("editBox1")
End Sub

This code works strangely.
I don't understand why this is so.
Public Sub MyTest()
    TextInEditBox = "1"
    myRibbon.InvalidateControl ("editBox1")
    
    TextInEditBox = "2"
    myRibbon.InvalidateControl ("editBox2") 
End Sub

If I do this, then only the last value will be inserted into both editBox.

Why can't I insert two different values ​​into editBox1 and editBox2? I would appreciate any help.

I solved the problem. It is necessary to separate macros and variables. Like this:
XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI 
                   onLoad="OpenFile"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
<tab 
              id="customTab" 
              label="Exsem" 
<tabs>
        <editBox
              id = "editBox1"
              getText = "MacroGetText1" />
        <editBox
              id = "editBox2"
              getText = "MacroGetText2" />

VBA
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI
Public text1 As String, text2 As String
Global TextInEditBox1 As String, TextInEditBox2 As String

Sub OpenFile(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
            Set myRibbon = ribbon                                                                      
End Sub

Private Sub MacroGetText1(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef text1)
    text1 = TextInEditBox1
End Sub

Private Sub MacroGetText2(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef text2)
    text2 = TextInEditBox2
End Sub

Sub NowEverythingIsFine()
TextInEditBox1 = "1"
TextInEditBox2 = "2"
myRibbon.Invalidate
End Sub


Since the control is passed as a parameter, you can use the same callback method for both editboxes, you just need to check the id before you return the value:
Private Sub MacroGetText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef text1)
    If control.ID = "editBox1" Then
        text1 = TextInEditBox1
    ElseIf control.ID = "editBox2" Then
        text1 = TextInEditBox2
    Else
        text1 = "Something else"
    End If
End Sub


Yes, you are right.
But this does not solve the original question.
I still could not find a way to write different values ​​into editboxes  using one overridable variable.

OK, I see. It looks like Excel combines the two invalidate-commands behind the scenes somehow, because if you debug you see that the value in TextInEditBox is 2 both times MacroGetText is called.
